# lua recursive repl on error?

Tags: error-handling, lua

In many scheme/lisp dialects, when an error occurs, a "recursive repl" is popped up ... one can execute scheme/lisp code at the frame where the error occured, and go up/down the stack.

Is it possible to do something similar to this in lua?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [debug.debug](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.debug).